# abort exception on Android 11

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have recently updated my app to use react-native expo SDK42, and I started seeing these crashes in the google play console crashes log. I did not get any complaint from users and could not reproduce, but they appear more and more in the play console - always on Android 11 (SDK30).
Can anyone please shed some light?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.gevahim.vatview <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000004e9fc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+180)
  #00  pc 00000000005703e0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2320)
  #00  pc 0000000000013ab0  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+80)
  #00  pc 0000000000006ec8  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+336)
  #00  pc 00000000003b196c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::EglManager::damageFrame(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&)+268)
  #00  pc 00000000003a44ec  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, android::uirenderer::LightInfo const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode> > > const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfoVisualizer*)+84)
  #00  pc 00000000003ada0c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+1076)
  #00  pc 00000000003afd90  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+480)
  #00  pc 000000000039e114  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+220)
  #00  pc 00000000003bfd90  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+88)
  #00  pc 000000000001567c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+260)
  #00  pc 0000000000014f14  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+412)
  #00  pc 00000000000b10e8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050a58  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.